How to solve a spring-mass differential equation with impulse at $t=\pi$ without Laplace transform?
Consider the differential equation
$$x''+x=F_0\delta(t-\pi)$$
with $x(0)=0$ and $x'(0)=1$.
I can solve this using Laplace transform.
The result I find is
$$x(t)=\begin{cases}\sin{(t)}\ \ \ \ \ &t\leq \pi \\ \sin{(t)}(1-F_0)\ \ \ \ \ &t\geq \pi\end{cases}$$
My question is about how to solve this differential equation without Laplace transform.
Let's think about the system as an undamped spring-mass system. The input to the system is an impulse of magnitude $F_0$ at time $\pi$.
For $t<\pi$ we have a simple homogeneous equation and the solution is
$$x(t)=\sin{(t)}$$
Note that $x(\pi)=0$ and $x'(\pi)=-1$.
At $t=\pi$ the impulse changes the velocity to $F_0$.
To solve the system for $t\geq\pi$ I once again solved
$$x''+x=0$$
with the initial conditions
$$x(\pi)=0$$
$$x'(\pi)=F_0$$
Since the solution is
$$x(t)=c_1\cos{(t)}+c_2\sin{(t)}$$
and
$$x'(t)=-c_1\sin{(t)}+c_2\cos{(t)}$$
the constants come out to $c_1=0$ and $c_2=-F_0$.
The solution is thus
$$x(t)=-F_0\sin{(t)}$$
Why do I have to, apparently, add in the solution obtained for $t<\pi$?
I think the mistake I am making is related to the initial conditions when I solved for $t>\pi$ but I am not sure.

For $t<\pi$ and $t>\pi$ we have a homogeneous differential equation,
$$
x''+x=0. \tag{1}
$$
You already found the solution for $t<\pi$:
$$
x(t)=\sin(t)\qquad(t<\pi). \tag{2}
$$
The general solution to $(1)$ for $t>\pi$ is
$$
x(t)=c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t)\qquad(t>\pi). \tag{3}
$$
The coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ are determined by the following conditions:

$x(t)$ is continuous at $t=\pi$:
$$
x(\pi+0)=x(\pi-0) \implies c_1\cos(\pi)+c_2\sin(\pi)=\sin(\pi) \implies c_1=0; \tag{4}
$$

$x'(t)$ has a discontinuity at $t=\pi$ given by
\begin{align}
x'(\pi+0)-x'(\pi-0)&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\pi-\varepsilon}^{\pi+\varepsilon}x''(t)\,dt \\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\pi-\varepsilon}^{\pi+\varepsilon}[-x(t)+F_0\delta(t-\pi)]\,dt \\
&=F_0, \phantom{\int} \tag{5}
\end{align}
so
$$
c_2\cos(\pi)-\cos(\pi)=F_0 \implies c_2=1-F_0. \tag{6}
$$


Therefore, it follows from $(3), (4)$ and $(6)$ that
$$
x(t)=(1-F_0)\sin(t)\qquad(t>\pi), \tag{7}
$$
the same solution obtained using the Laplace transform.

Where does (6) come from?

I guess it comes from $x'(\pi^+)-x'(\pi^-)$. In terms of the theory, what is the difference between the solution $x(t)=-F_0\sin{(t)}$ and $x(t)=(1-F_0)\sin{(t)}$? In other words, why would one think of writing the limit in the group of expressions (5)? Is this a case of $x(t)=-F_0\sin{(t)}$ being a particular solution and $x(t)=\sin{(t)}$ being a homogeneous solution? It doesn't seem to be the case, since to arrive at both cases we used the homogeneous solution with different initial conditions, but I am wondering.

The key is this sentence in your post: "At $t=\pi$ the impulse changes the velocity to $F_0$." It should be "(...) changes the velocity by $F_0$." If the particle velocity at $t=\pi^{-}$ were $0$, at $t=\pi^+$ it would be $F_0$, so the solution after $t=\pi$ would be $x(t)=-F_0\sin(t)$. However, since the velocity at $t=\pi^{-}$ is $-1$, the impulse changes it to $-1+F_0$, so the solution after $t=\pi$ is $x(t)=(1-F_0)\sin(t)$.

The general solution of an inhomogenous linear second order equation is the general solution of the homogenous equation plus a special solution of the inhomogneous equation.
The special solution with a delta-pulse of the system at rest is a system at rest for $t<t_0$ and starting from $x(t_0)=0$ with velocity $x'(t_0)=F_0$ performing the sinus oscillation starting with a zero at $t=t_0$
$$\begin{align} x(t<t_0)&=0, \quad  x'(t_0) = F_0 \\
                x'(t<0)&=0 , \quad x'(t>t_0) = F_0 \cos(t-t_0), \\
                x(t<t_0)&=0 , \quad  x(t>t_0)  = F_0 \sin(t-t_0)\end{align} $$
or
$$x(t)= F_0 \ \theta(t-t_0)\ \sin (t-t_0)$$
Verification
$$x'= F_0 \left(\delta(t-t_0)\ \sin(t-t_0)+ \theta(t-t_0)\  \cos(t-t_0)\right) = F_0\left( \delta(t-t_0) \  \sin(t-t)+ \theta(t-t_0) \ \cos(t-t_0)\right)$$
$$x'' = F_0 \ \delta(t-t_0) \ \cos(t-t_0)- F_0 \theta(t-t0) \ \sin(t-t_0)= F_0   \ \delta(t-t_0) \ \cos(t-t) - x$$
only using the fact, that a product   $$\delta(t-t_0) f(t)=\delta(t-t_0) f(t_0)= $$ evaluates at a point if subject to integrations.
To this special solution any harmonic oscillation $x_{gen}= A \sin(t-t_1)$ can be added. The solution with the start conditions $x(0)=0, x'(0)=1$ is $x_{gen}=\sin t,$ because the pulse at $t_0=\pi$ is starting at a later time.
